# Switching buffers and frames in Org mode

Tags: emacs, navigation, shortcut, org-mode

I'm using `M-<left>` and `M-<right>` to cycle buffers in Emacs 24 (with `previous-buffer` and `next-buffer` respectively). I also use `C-<tab>` to cycle through frames.

In Org mode those keys are bound to specific functions. The problem is, if I position the cursor in a neutral area (over whitespace), the keys register and fail; I'd like them to fall back to the behaviour detailed above.

Sadly I don't speak Lisp so I can't tacle the problem on my own.

- How can I define a shortcut to custom behaviour when over whitespace in Org mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue only presents itself in `org-mode`, then my best guess is that there are key definitions in that major mode that are trumping your global key settings.  One option would be to remove the `org-mode-map` definitions that are affecting your global settings, and reassign them to different keys.  To remove `org-mode-map` definitions, here is one possible method:

```
(eval-after-load "org" '(progn

  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-left>") nil)

  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-right>") nil)

  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") nil)  ))
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP doesn't want to disable the defaults of the mentioned bindings in 'org' but add a fall back.